# Return proxied class in many to many relation, Django 2.0

Tags: django, django-models, django-2.0

From another installed app, I have models like this

```
class Organization(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

class Person(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

class Membership(model.Model):

    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        Organization,
        related_name='memberships',
        # memberships will go away if the org does
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        help_text="A link to the Organization in which the Person is a member.")

    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        related_name='memberships',
        null=True,
        # Membership will just unlink if the person goes away
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        help_text="A link to the Person that is a member of the Organization.")
```

In my app, I need to add some method to some of the models. So I have a model like

```
class ProxiedOrganization(other_app.models.Organization):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    special_attribute = 'foo'


class ProxiedPerson(other_app.models.Person):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def special_method(self):
         print('I do something special')
```

When I get the memberships from an organization, they are of type `other_app.models.Person`.

```
> type(proxied_org_instance.memberships[0].person)
<class 'other_app.models.Person'>
```

but, I'd like them to be my instances of my proxy class

```
> type(proxied_org_instance.memberships[0].person)
<class 'my_app.models.ProxiedPerson'>
```

Is there a good way of doing this? Is this the kind of thing that I can do with a query manager? The solution must work for Django 2.0.

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891880/django-proxy-model-and-foreignkey, but none of the proposed solutions worked for me with Django 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted Matt Schinckel's [work on overriding proxy model relations](https://schinckel.net/2015/05/13/django-proxy-model-relations/), for a solution that will work with Django 2.0 and 2.1. The code is available as a [library on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/django-proxy-overrides/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to either put a ForeignKey in `Organization` to `ProxiedPerson`. For example:

```
class MemberShip(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        ProxyPerson,
        related_name='memberships',
        null=True,
        # Membership will just unlink if the person goes away
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        help_text="A link to the Person that is a member of the Organization.")
```

or you can get the proxy person instance by:

```
proxy_person = ProxyPerson.objects.get(pk=proxied_org_instance.memberships[0].person.pk)
```

Or

```
proxy_persons = ProxyPerson.objects.filter(
                    pk__in = proxied_org_instance.memberships.all().values_list('person_id')
                )
```

As per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)

> The MyPerson class operates on the same database table as its parent
>   Person class. In particular, any new instances of Person will also be
>   accessible through MyPerson, and vice-versa

Means you can access `Person` Instance through `ProxyPerson` Instance or vice versa.

Comment: This is helpful, but I'd like the change the behavior of `proxied_org_instance.memberships` to, by default, have `ProxiedPersons` not have to cast them to `ProxiedPerson` after making the query.

Comment: Hmm.. but, I want to use the data in the `other_app`'s `Membership` table. Maybe I can do this by created an unmanaged `Membership` model in `my_app`