# Subclassing Django model only for behavior

Tags: django, django-1.8

I have a model `Property` with certain fields and a relevant method:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table)
    field1 = models.CharField()
    field2 = models.IntegerField()
    field3 = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def post():
        pass
```

But then I have a definite number of types of columns, conceptually speaking. There is no difference in the fields, only in how the behavior of a certain method is implemented:

```
class Property1(Property):
    def post():
        # execute behavior for Property1
        pass

class Property2(Property):
    def post():
        # execute behavior for Property2
        pass
```

and so on.

If I turned `Property` into an abstract base model class and have the rest inherit it, I will end up with different tables for each property. I am not sure I want that. All tables will look the same, which is redundant.

But at the same time when running a query to get all properties in a table and calling `post()` I want the corresponding behavior to be executed:

```
for prop in table.property_set.all():
    prop.post()
```

What are my options?

Answer (score 3):

For that, you can use [proxy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) model. Try like this:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table)
    field1 = models.CharField()
    field2 = models.IntegerField()
    field3 = models.BooleanField()


class Property1(Property):
    class Meta:
       proxy = True

    def post():
        # execute behavior for Property1
        pass

class Property2(Property):

    class Meta:
       proxy = True

    def post():
        # execute behavior for Property2
        pass
```

As per documentation:

> The MyPerson class operates on the same database table as its parent Person class. In particular, any new instances of Person will also be accessible through MyPerson, and vice-versa:

So you can get the proxy instances like this:

```
Property1.objects.filter(pk__in=table.property_set.all())
```

Comment: That is missing the last requirement I mentioned which is that the appropriate instances of each subclass would be returned instead of the base class.

Comment: @dabadaba please see my updated answer. hope it helps.

Comment: That doesn't really help. All that does is force cast all table properties into the given subclass, no matter if it was an instance of that subclass to begin with.

Comment: maybe you can look into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891880/django-proxy-model-and-foreignkey